# MY GUITAR AMP STOPS PRODUCING SOUND

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar, amplifiers, sound

whenever i strum my guitar the amp stops producing sound for a couple of seconds and then the sound returns again.
Anyone has the same problem / knows what i can do?
thanks in advance.
(amp = line6 spider iv and guitar = epiphone custom)

Comment: Is there a compressor switched on?

Comment: no, i am not using one.

Comment: **HAVE YOU GOT THE DISTORTION/OVERDRIVE SWITCHED ON?**

Answer (score 1):

Does it happen at any volume? try low gain, high master and other combinations. Also try with all effects and modeling off. If it happens at any volume it sounds like the input signal is inadvertently causing the amp to clip and go into some type of protection mode. Check any connections you can like cables, input jack and the fuse. If it still happens you will probably have to have it looked at by a tech.